# How to make sidebar with children elements in Vitepress?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, vitepress

I'm trying to represent my folder tree in the sidebar but when I click on one of the `Group` parent elements, the children elements are not rendered.

[image]

Another thing that's weird is that the `Group` elements have no `cursor: pointer` css property, like you would expect on a clickable object. This is my `.vitepress/config.ts`

```
export default {
  title: "blub docs",
  description: "blub",
  themeConfig: {
    nav: [
      { text: 'Home', link: '/' },
      { text: 'Examples', link: '/markdown-examples' }
    ],
    sidebar: {
      '/': [
        {
          text: 'Group 1',
          collapsible: true,
          children: [
            '/group1/page1.md',
            '/group1/page2.md',
          ],
        },
        {
          text: 'Group 2',
          collapsible: true,
          children: [
            '/group2/page1.md',
            '/group2/page2.md',
          ],
        },
      ],
    }
  }
}
```

I've also commented out the `layout` from `root/index.md` so that the sidebar is visible on the landing page (if that is relevant):

```
[//]: # (layout: home)
```

This is the default layout of vitepress. I've implemented a custom layout but ended up having exactly the same issue.

Comment: I did not try this, but as I can see on their documentation: https://vitepress.dev/reference/default-theme-sidebar#collapsible-sidebar-groups
propertyName for children is `items`, not `children`

Comment: This renders the child elements below the parent but has no indent and the parent is still not a collapsible object. The children can't be hidden.

Comment: And also, to enable collapsing. instead of `collapsible`, you should add `collapsed`: true/false, and then you will get toggle button, also from their docs

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as of vitepress version `1.0.0-alpha.61` this is the correct way of configuring a collapsible multi-layer sidebar:

```
sidebar: [
    {
      text: 'Group 1',
      items: [
        {
          text: 'Group 2',
          collapsed: true,
          items: [
            { text: 'blub1', link: '/group1/page1.md' },
            { text: 'blub2', link: '/group1/page2.md' },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      text: 'Group 2',
      collapsed: true,
      items: [
        { text: 'blub1', link: '/group2/page1.md' },
        { text: 'blub2', link: '/group2/page2.md' },
      ],
    },
],
```

source: https://vitepress.dev/reference/default-theme-sidebar#collapsible-sidebar-groups